# Iterating over pandas columns and calculating new columns in each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
d = {'A': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'B': [20, 30, 40, 50],'C': [30, 40, 50, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    A        B       C
    10       20      30  
    20       30      40 
    30       40      50    
    40       50      60
```

I am trying to build a loop such that it creates three new columns (one in each iteration) using a complex formula wherein only one of them is increased by 10% while the other two remain the same in each iteration.

The formula applied each time is: sqrt(((A ** 2)*B)+((B ** 2)*C))

So the desired output is -

```
    A        B       C      X_A      X_B       X_C
    10       20      30     120.08   129.30    123.29
    20       30      40     224.77   238.24    227.16
    30       40      50     351.51   369.32    352.14
    40       50      60     496.79   519.13    494.98
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `eval`

We can use some dynamic string interpolation and `pandas.DataFrame.eval`
REQUIRES Python 3.6

```
fbase = '(((({0:}) ** 2) * ({1:})) + ((({1:}) ** 2) * ({2:}))) ** .5'.format

df.eval(f"""\
X_A = {fbase('1.1 * A', 'B', 'C')}
X_B = {fbase('A', '1.1 * B', 'C')}
X_C = {fbase('A', 'B', '1.1 * C')}
""")

    A   B   C         X_A         X_B         X_C
0  10  20  30  120.083304  129.305839  123.288280
1  20  30  40  224.766546  238.243573  227.156334
2  30  40  50  351.511024  369.323706  352.136337
3  40  50  60  496.789694  519.133894  494.974747
```

---

Lest dynamic but doesn't require Python 3.6

```
df.eval("""\
X_A = ((((1.1 * A) ** 2) * (B)) + (((B) ** 2) * (C))) ** .5
X_B = '((((A) ** 2) * (1.1 * B)) + (((1.1 * B) ** 2) * (C))) ** .5'
X_C = ((((A) ** 2) * (B)) + (((B) ** 2) * (1.1 * C))) ** .5
""")

    A   B   C         X_A         X_B         X_C
0  10  20  30  120.083304  129.305839  123.288280
1  20  30  40  224.766546  238.243573  227.156334
2  30  40  50  351.511024  369.323706  352.136337
3  40  50  60  496.789694  519.133894  494.974747
```

---

#### Numpy-ish

```
def f(m):
  A, B, C = m.T
  return (((A ** 2) * B) + ((B ** 2) * C)) ** .5

v = df.values
m = np.eye(3) * .1 + np.ones((3, 3))

r = f((v * m[:, None]).reshape(-1, 3)).reshape(3, -1)

df.assign(**dict(zip('X_A X_B X_C'.split(), r)))

    A   B   C         X_A         X_B         X_C
0  10  20  30  120.083304  129.305839  123.288280
1  20  30  40  224.766546  238.243573  227.156334
2  30  40  50  351.511024  369.323706  352.136337
3  40  50  60  496.789694  519.133894  494.974747
```

Comment: Thank you piRSquared. This worked perfectly! I went for the numpy formulation

Answer (score 4):

You have two questions in it .

*1st maybe you did not aware of it .
Your data data type is string. 
We need convert to int firstly*

```
df=df.astype(int)
```

Then we using `div` and `add`

```
pd.concat([df,df.div(10).add(df.sum(1),0).add_prefix('X_')],axis=1)
Out[1082]: 
    A   B   C  X_A  X_B  X_C
0  10  20  30   61   62   63
1  20  30  40   92   93   94
2  30  40  50  123  124  125
3  40  50  60  154  155  156
```

Comment: Thank you Wen. This approach looks very promising. I have updated my original question slightly to request a resolution for my actual formula. How would a multi term complex formula be applied to this solution?

Comment: @kartriter `(df.A^2*df.B+df.B^2*df.C).pow(1/2)`

Comment: @kartriter i am not quite clear about the logic `df.mul(1.01).mul((df.A^2*df.B+df.B^2*df.C).pow(1/2),axis=0)
` you should change it by you real formula

Comment: Thank you for your help Wen. It was very useful too. The method piRsquared is what I was looking for to be more precise. Thank you once again